# External range throwing error 400

Tags: vba, range

I am struggling with something:

The code I need is:

```
Set myrange = WS.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 10))
```

But this is resulting in a 400 error.

Strangely, either of the two lines work fine:

```
Set myrange = WS.Range("a1:b2")

Set myrange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 10))
```

So it appears that I am only in trouble if I combine an external sheet reference (`WS`) with referring to the range using cells.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Where is the code that defines your `WS` variable?

Comment: How are your `WS` and `myrange` variables dimensioned?  As in what type of variable are they?

Comment: I define them as

`dim WS as worksheet
`dim myrange as range

WS gets its value from an array that I have defined earlier in the code:

`set WS = worksheets(wsarray(i))

WS is recognized correctly when I use the WS.Range("a1:b2") syntax, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: You need to edit your post with the code.  Don't put it in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the sheet in each part of the code:

```
Set myrange = WS.Range(WS.Cells(1, 1), WS.Cells(10, 10))
'or
With WS
Set myrange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(10, 10))
```

Each Range whether it is called using the Range object or the Cells object needs to have a defined sheet.